# C# Grouping of included entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

```
 public class Offer
{
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
    public string OfferName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string PartNo { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
    public Offer Offer { get; set; }
}
public class OfferSum
{
    public int OfferId { get; set; }
    public string OfferName { get; set; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSum { get; set; }
}
```

I have 3 classes: Offer, Items and view called OfferSum. I would like to use LINQ to populate OfferSum view.

```
FindAll() is returning IQueryable<Offer>
```

ItemCount should return count of items included in offer, TotalSum should return Price * Quantity of items included in offer. But I dont know how to write the query.

I have something like this:

```
var result = FindAll().
            Include(x=> x.Items).
            GroupBy(x => new { x.OfferId, x.OfferName})
            
            .Select(b => new OfferSum
            {
          OfferName = b.Key.OfferName,
          OfferId = b.Key.OfferId,
          ItemCount = b.Count(dont know),
          TotalSum = b.Sum(dont know)
          

        });
```

Comment: `ItemCount = b.Key.Items.Count()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. Written using query syntax because it is more clear for understanding.

```cs
var query = 
    from o in FindAll()
    from i in o.Items
    group i by new { o.OfferId, o.OfferName } into g
    select new OfferSum
    {
        OfferName = g.Key.OfferName,
        OfferId = g.Key.OfferId,
        ItemCount = g.Count(),
        TotalSum = g.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity)
    };
```